# Get a list of Keys from NSDictionary containing NSNumber bools where the value is @YES

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I'm trying to get an array of keys where the value for the corresponding key in an `NSDictionary` is @`YES`.

For EG,:
Starting Dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dict = @{@"key1" : @YES, @"key2": @YES, @"key3": @NO, @"key4": @NO};
```

Desired Result:

```
NSArray* array = @[@"key1", @"key2"];
```

I tried doing this with NSPredicates and subpredicates but couldn't find one that did what i wanted. My "working" but ugly solution is:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSDictionary* dict = @{@"key1" : @YES, @"key2": @YES, @"key3": @NO, @"key4": @NO};
for (NSString* key in [dict allKeys]) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:key] isEqualToNumber:@YES])
        [array addObject:key];
}
```

What is a better way of doing this, possibly with `NSPredicates`?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of abstracts a lot of the messiness away

```
NSArray *results = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
  return [obj isEqualToNumber:@YES];
}].allObjects;

NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the type of thing i knew i could do but didn't know how.